# How to make background image fade in with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, fade, fadein

I have this line of css for a image that I will fade in upon hover:

```
#social-links a:hover span  { background: url("/images/hover-light.jpg") no-repeat scroll -4px 42px transparent; }
```

It works and now I want to add a fade in effect from jquery to it. There are multiple `spans` so I assume I would have to the identifier `this` but I haven't used jquery in a while and do not remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#social-links a').mouseleave(
   function() {
     $(this)  // anchor tag from which mouseleave happen
       .find('span')
       .css({ 'background': 'your background css' })
});
```

For `fadeIn()` you can do:

```
$('#social-links a').mouseleave(
   function() {
     $(this)  // anchor tag from which mouseleave happen
       .find('span')
       .fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: thank you, so after do I add the .fade() function aroung the .css() function?

Comment: thanks @thecodeparadox , but i tried both of them. the first one with my css input into it and then the last one and neither of them work. I dont even think the identifiers/locator ids are finding the elements for some odd reason...

Comment: i dont think it will work with .mouseleave, for whatever reason, but I am working on getting it to work with animate opacity.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a perfect example of a background image fading. With little modifications, it's perfect for your purpose.

http://www.jasperrooswinkel.com/smooth-fullscreen-background-slideshow-in-jquery/